# How to get properties from active CUDA device?

Tags: cuda, nvidia

The well know code for getting properties from CUDA devices (!) is enumerating over all devices, and getting properties from then. Then I see such piece, that activates given device.

I have problem in reverse -- let's say the device is already chosen, and I would like to get properties for it (the active one), not for all devices present in the system.

*I hope I wrote this in correct way, because I am new to CUDA.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just call `cudaGetDevice()` to get the device number of the active context, then call `cudaGetDeviceProperties` to get the properties of that device. In code that would be something like:

```
int device;
cudaGetDevice(&device);

struct cudaDeviceProp props;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, device);
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, never compiled or tested. Use at own risk]

Answer (score 4):

I have a script here that identifies all the active devices, and for each one returns some useful information on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

  int nDevices;
  cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);
  
  printf("Number of devices: %d\n", nDevices);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < nDevices; i++) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, i);
    printf("Device Number: %d\n", i);
    printf("  Device name: %s\n", prop.name);
    printf("  Memory Clock Rate (MHz): %d\n",
           prop.memoryClockRate/1024);
    printf("  Memory Bus Width (bits): %d\n",
           prop.memoryBusWidth);
    printf("  Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): %.1f\n",
           2.0*prop.memoryClockRate*(prop.memoryBusWidth/8)/1.0e6);
    printf("  Total global memory (Gbytes) %.1f\n",(float)(prop.totalGlobalMem)/1024.0/1024.0/1024.0);
    printf("  Shared memory per block (Kbytes) %.1f\n",(float)(prop.sharedMemPerBlock)/1024.0);
    printf("  minor-major: %d-%d\n", prop.minor, prop.major);
    printf("  Warp-size: %d\n", prop.warpSize);
    printf("  Concurrent kernels: %s\n", prop.concurrentKernels ? "yes" : "no");
    printf("  Concurrent computation/communication: %s\n\n",prop.deviceOverlap ? "yes" : "no");
  }
}
```

**Note**: place code snippet in a `.cu` file and compile with `nvcc`.

For example on my desktop with one GPU the message on screen is:

```
Number of devices: 1
Device Number: 0
  Device name: Quadro K5200
  Memory Clock Rate (MHz): 2933
  Memory Bus Width (bits): 256
  Peak Memory Bandwidth (GB/s): 192.3
  Total global memory (Gbytes) 7.4
  Shared memory per block (Kbytes) 48.0
  minor-major: 5-3
  Warp-size: 32
  Concurrent kernels: yes
  Concurrent computation/communication: yes
```